# Spring boot CORS withCredentials

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors

I am getting **Credential is not supported if the CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is '*'** error. Below is the response of preflight request

[image]

As you can see the value of **access-control-allow-origin** is set to *****. It should be value of origin header in the request. Because of this ***** I am getting above error.

If I invoke preflight from CURL, I get the correct response,

[image]

Below is my CORS filter,

```
@Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        List<String> allowedMethods = Arrays.asList("GET", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "POST", "HEAD", "OPTIONS");
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedOriginPatterns(corsUrls);
        config.setAllowedMethods(allowedMethods);
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedHeader(ALL);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
```

But for actual request it sets value of **access-control-allow-origin** to value of origin header in the request.

Comment: Not sure what happens here but your code also sets allowed methods to all of them but response headers says only GET. I noticed that the response seems to come from nginx so there might be some proxy configuration that needs changing...

Comment: Hey @grekier, when I do a preflight from CURL it seems to be working. I have updated that info to the question

Comment: To me, it seems that curl get to Spring Boot but the browser did not. Do you have a proxy in between? If so, can you share its config?